# How to define Fabricator for namespace class

Tags: ruby, mongoid, fabrication-gem

I want to define Fabricator for class has namespace like 'Foo::Bar'.
Tell me the way it can work.

Here my codes.

models/foo.rb

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :foo_container, polymorphic: true

  field :xxx ....
end
```

models/foo/bar.rb

```
class Foo::Bar < Foo
  field :yyy ....
  field :zzz ....
end
```

data/fabricators/foo_bar_fabricator.rb

```
Fabricator(:foo_bar, class_name: 'Foo::Bar') do
   yyy 'MyString'
   zzz 'MyString'
end
```

When I tried to create Fabricatior object on parino console but error occurred.

```
> Fabricate(:foo_bar)
> NoMethodError: undefined method `new?' for nil:NilClass
  .... stack messages
```

When I tried to create other Fabricator object wasn't namespace class like 'User', it went right.

Answer (score 6):

According to Fabrication's documentation on [creating objects](http://www.fabricationgem.org/#!defining-fabricators):

> To use a different name from the class, you must specify `from: :symbolized_class_name` as the second argument.

So the following should work:

```
Fabricator(:foo_bar, from: 'Foo::Bar') do
  yyy 'MyString'
  zzz 'MyString'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
Fabricator(:foo_bar, class_name: :'Foo::Bar') do
    xxx {Faker::Company.name}
    yyy 'Mystring'
end
```